# How to view diff between commit sha in remote and local

Tags: git

In example:

Local repo is a fork of github repo.
History of local looks like:

- Local commit 4
- Upstream commit 4
- Upstream commit 3
- Upstream commit 2
- Local commit 3
- Local commit 2
- Local commit 1
- Upstream commit 1

History of remote looks like:

- Upstream commit 4
- Upstream commit 3
- Upstream commit 2
- Upstream commit 1

How can I view diff between remote "Upstream commit 2" and local "Upstream commit 2"?

Answer (score 1):

References to remote tracking branches are stored on your machine in the refs/remotes.  To see the differences between your local branch and the branch you most recently fetch/pull-ed.

```
git diff MyRemote/MyBranch MyBranch
```

To fetch the most recent commits from the remote branch, and not affect your local branch.

```
git fetch MyRemote MyBranch
```

Then diff as above.

Comment: thank you, but I need diff between commits, not branches, as I think.

Comment: if you have the sha of the commits, just type "git  diff MYREMOTESHA MYLOCALSHA"  to find the sha of the commits  you want use 'git log --oneline -32 MyBranch MyRemote/MyBranch"

Comment: The problem is - SHA is the same.

Comment: if the SHA is the same, the files (and the history) that are tracked by git are identical (except for maybe the line endings, depending how they are configured).  The command 'git diff' will not find any differences and will produced no output.  If you want to get the difference between your working directory and the commit use "git diff SHA".